# Write a *nix command on Windows cmd prompt

Tags: cmd, hashicorp-vault

I am trying to execute this *nix command found [here](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/getting-started-dynamic-secrets?in=vault/getting-started#create-a-role) on cmd prompt:

```
vault write aws/roles/my-role \
        credential_type=iam_user \
        policy_document=-<<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1426528957000",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
EOF
```

So far, i have tried different combinations/variations such as writing the command on a single line such as this:

```
C:\Users\user-name>vault write aws/roles/my-role credential_type=iam_user policy_document={"Version": "2012-10-17","Statement": [{"Sid": "Stmt1426528957000","Effect": "Allow","Action": ["ec2:*"],"Resource": ["*"]}]}
Failed to parse K=V data: invalid key/value pair "2012-10-17,Statement:": format must be key=value
```

or on multiple lines such as this:

```
C:\Users\user-name>vault write aws/roles/my-role ^
More? credential_type=iam_user ^
More? policy_document=-^<^<EOF ^
More? { ^
More? ^"Version^" : ^"2012-10-17^", ^
More? ^"Statement^" : [ ^
More? { ^
More? ^"Sid^" : ^"Stmt1426528957000^", ^
More? ^"Effect^" : ^"Allow^", ^
More? ^"Action^" : [ ^
More? ^"ec2:*^" ^
More? ], ^
More? ^"Resource^": [ ^
More? ^"*^" ^
More? ] ^
More? } ^
More? ] ^
More? } ^
More? EOF
Failed to parse K=V data: invalid key/value pair "{": format must be key=value
```

**Note 1**: It works on Git Bash, i am just curious how to get it to work on cmd prompt.

**Note 2**:

```
C:\Users\user-name>where vault
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\vault.exe

$ which vault
/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin/vault
```

Comment: Could you give us the result of  `where vault` on windows and the result of `which vault` on git-bash ?

Comment: Hi @Zilog80, done, in "Note 2".

Comment: For ref, there is no stream indirection in batch ( << EOF ), so your one liner is the best approach. You should try `vault write aws/roles/my-role credential_type=iam_user policy_document="{""Version"": ""2012-10-17"",""Statement"": [{""Sid"": ""Stmt1426528957000"",""Effect"": ""Allow"",""Action"": [""ec2:*""],""Resource"": [""*""]}]}"`, i guess AWS vault try to parse the policy as arguments, using quotes should prevent that.

Comment: It does not work, i am getting `Failed to parse K=V data: invalid key/value pair "2012-10-17,Statement:": format must be key=value`

Comment: Maybe without spaces ? Try `vault write aws/roles/my-role credential_type=iam_user policy_document="{""Version"":""2012-10-17"",""Statement"":[{""Sid"":""Stmt1426528957000"",""Effect"":""Allow"",""Action"":[""ec2:*""],""Resource"":[""*""]}]}"`

Comment: hmm, `* cannot parse policy document: "{\"Version:2012-10-17,Statement:[{Sid:Stmt1426528957000,Effect:Allow,Action:[ec2:*],Resource:[*]}]}"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231164/discussion-between-zilog80-and-jumping-monkey).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in cmd this seemed to have worked:

```
vault write aws/roles/test-role credential_type=iam_user policy_document={\"Version\":\"2012-10-17\",\"Statement\":[{\"Sid\":\"Stmt1426528957000\",\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Action\":[\"ec2:*\"],\"Resource\":[\"*\"]}]}
```

Success! Data written to: aws/roles/test-role

I've removed spaces from json, escaped every double quote character and put everything in one line.

Comment: Hi Wojciech, i am not able to validate your answer as i am not using Vault anymore, but i am guessing that it is right, so i am accepting it. Thanks for taking your time to answer the question.